# MYSQL Using incremented column in case when statement

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create a column when selecting data from a table to auto_increment the row count and the best solution I have found is to use `ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( order by Date DESC) AS row_` because it is consistent with the order clause and has proven to work in my situation.

However I can't use the new column `row_` when creating stats in a `case when` statement.

For example, I have the following statement:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( order by Date Desc) AS row_
      ,CASE WHEN row_ = 1 then 8 else 0 end as stat1
      ,CASE WHEN row_ = 2 then 2 else 0 end as stat2
FROM tblr R
JOIN tblrn RR ON R.RUniqueID = RR.WRID 
WHERE WHID = @VHID AND RDate < @RD
ORDER BY RDate DESC;
```

However I get an error saying: `Unknown column 'row_' in field list`.

Im really looking for something where I can have a table (`row_` being calculated by the `ROW_NUMBER()...` section):

| row_ | col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | blah | blah |
| 2 | blah | blah |
| 3 | blah | blah |

and be able to use row_ in a case when situation so create another column to look like:

| row_ | col1 | col2 | stat1 | stat2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | blah | blah | 8 | 0 |
| 2 | blah | blah | 0 | 2 |
| 3 | blah | blah | 0 | 0 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly use the `ROW_NUMBER()` function within you `CASE` clause Like below:

```sql
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( order by Date Desc) AS row_,
CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( order by Date Desc) = 1 THEN 8 ELSE 0 END AS stat1,
CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( order by Date Desc) = 2 THEN 2 ELSE 0 END AS stat2
FROM tblr R
JOIN tblrn RR ON R.RUniqueID = RR.WRID 
WHERE WHID = @VHID AND RDate < @RD
ORDER BY RDate DESC;
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=0239622aed105994e3015d6c9ca5cd8f)

Comment: Wow, simply elegant! Can't believe I missed that. Thank you